# Hiding sibling if UL is empty with css

Tags: css

If I have the following:

```
<div class="notifications__list">
   <ul class="list_container">
   </ul>
   <div class="notice">Nothing for you</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to hide `.notice` if there are item's in the `ul`?

I tried `:empty` tag but I can't quite get it to work.

Comment: You can't use CSS for this. Jquery or Javascript would work. You need to set an if clause and that can't be set in CSS. Would you want an answer in JQuery?

Comment: @Gosi no thanks, I don't want this in jQuery. thank you for your response

Comment: @Gosi, from my simplified viewpoint, you can look at CSS as a (huge) list of 'if clauses': **if** `.selector` **then** modify `{ properties }`. Not trying to outsmart you, this is how I really look at CSS.

Comment: That's nice, I learnt something new @RenevanderLende :D upvoting your answer as well

Comment: @Gosi, humbly accepting the compliment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you, but in a slightly different setup:

- make the `.notice` a `<span>` inside the `<ul>`
- and use a CSS selector which includes `li` to hide the `.notice` (make it `display: none`)

**Also make sure** to place the `.notice` element *after* the `<li>` element, as this is the default usage of the **'+'** selector. [w3schools: CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), check the difference with the **'~'** (tilde) selector.

Check the snippet: `<ul>` without/with `<li>`

```css
ul>li+.notice { display: none }
```

```html
<h3>ul 1</h3>
<div class="notifications__list">
    <ul class="list_container">
        <li>got a li</li>
        <span class="notice">Nothing for you</span>
    </ul>
</div>
<h3>ul 2</h3>
<div class="notifications__list">
    <ul class="list_container">
        <span class="notice">Nothing for you</span>
    </ul>
</div>
<h3>ul 3</h3>
<div>
    <ul class="list_container">
        <span class="notice">Nothing for you 1</span>
        <li>got a li</li>
        <span class="notice">Nothing for you 2</span>
        <li>got a li</li>
        <span class="notice">Nothing for you 3</span>
        <span class="notice">Nothing for you 4</span>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @bryan, Cheers, mate! Has a funny side-effect too, I added a 3rd demo to show how you can toy with extra `<span>`s. Try adding `li:hover+span { display: initial }` for even some more fun!

Comment: For anyone reading this, PLEASE double check and make sure your `.notice` is AFTER your `<li>` or it will not be counted in this CSS

Comment: Hi @bryan, that is the default behaviour of the '+' selector. Here a link to [w3schools: CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for an elaborate explanation. Check the difference with the '~' (tilde) selector. Thanks for the heads up, though, as the difference is not always clear. Adding the warning (and link) to my answer.